# fast forward/reverse or jump to specific time in video minidlna streamed content to TV

Tags: 12.04, video, multimedia, dlna, minidlna

I am successfully using [minidlna](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiniDLNA) to stream content between my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop and a Samsung SMART TV with AllShare system. The only problem I see is that there is no way to jump to a specific point to a video. For example, if I want to fast forward to half way of a video that is being streamed, how can I do that?

Comment: This is how we do it: on the remote control for the TV skip forward or backward with the arrow keys, press INFO for the time line. To jump to a specific time in a movie press TOOLS for an on-screen menu to enable time search.

Comment: @Takkat why didn't you write  that as answer?